# Javascript/CSS Menu to replace contents in a specific area

Tags: javascript, css, menu

Im looking for a script or tutorial that shows how to create a menu similar to the one from a Firefox first run page: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/2.0.0.6/firstrun/

When you click a nav menu item on the left, the contents scroll into position in the main content area right of the menu items.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Careful in your implementation. I just pulled up your example in IE7 and it wasn't working all too well.

Answer (score 1):

You can code your own easily using Jquery [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

```
$(...).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you copy the one used on Firefox first page? It's distributed under a CC license.
http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/about/legal.html